# Отправка сообщения через Enter не работает

Tags: javascript, html, клавиатура, javascript-events

После ввода сообщения в соответствующую форму и нажатия Enter вместо отправки сообщения происходит обновление страницы. Форма Sent работает как нужно.

```
function sendMessage() {
            var messageField = document.getElementById("message");
            var`введите сюда код` userNameField = document.getElementById("username");
            var message = userNameField.value + ":" + messageField.value;
            ws.send(message);
            messageField.value = '';

        }
        document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  if (event.code == 'Enter') {
   sendMessage(message);
  }
})
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Просто напросто происходит submit формы. Вам нужно либо сделать обработчик onsubmit и делать e.preventDefault, либо вообще убрать форму, потому что она бесполезна при текущем коде вообще

Comment: Удалось решить проблему изменением самой формы, даже event.preventDefault() не пригодился.                                                                   
           <form onsubmit="return false">
        <input type="button"  name="Enter" value="Send..." onclick="sendMessage();"  />
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="message" size="40"/>
    </form>

Comment: Всё же проще убрать форм вообще. Зачем она?

Comment: Для возможности отправки сообщения не только по Enter , но и благодаря кнопочке "Send".

Comment: У вас при клике на Send отрабатывает js скрипт и в итоге form не задействована вообще никак.